# ASM is loading incorrectly due to local Gradle libraries

Tags: java, gradle

IllegalArgumentException occurs when I create an instance of ClassNode. If you decompile ClassNode, I can see that there is no ASM9 in Opcodes

[image: ClassNode code]

If I go to Opcodes and click download sources, it will be written that no sources were found for jdb-server:

[image: Sources not found warning]

I connect them via gradle, they don't use ASM:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('build/libraries/jdb-agent.jar')
    implementation files('build/libraries/jdb-server.jar')
}
```

If I remove this, there will be no error, but I need local libraries